# Wpf DatagridComboBoxColumn binding for two tables?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have to classes Books and Publishing Houses:

```
public partial class Books
{
    public Books()
    {
        this.Authors = new ObservableCollection<Authors>();
    }

    public int bID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int phID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> PubYear { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Edition { get; set; }

    public virtual PublishingHouse PublishingHouse { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Authors> Authors { get; set; }
}
public partial class PublishingHouse
{
    public PublishingHouse()
    {
        this.Books = new ObservableCollection<Books>();
    }

    public int phID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }    

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Books> Books { get; set; }
}
```

So i have Datagrid which shows me all of my books:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="booksViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Books}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="booksAuthorsViewSource" Source="{Binding Authors, Source={StaticResource booksViewSource}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="authorsViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Authors}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="publishingHouseViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:PublishingHouse}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource booksViewSource}" Margin="0,0,2,0">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="b ID" Binding="{Binding bID}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" Binding="{Binding Edition}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Year" Binding="{Binding PubYear}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="phIDComboBoxColumn" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding phID}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The thing i want, is to set the default value of my `phIDComboBoxColumn` to be taken from a book, but when i want to edit it, i want to see a list of `phId`'s of all avaliable `PublishingHouses`. Must i somehow bind 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' for two dataSources?

Comment: Assume there is a list of phId's of PublishingHouses in your `Combobox` and you select for example phId#3, if default value has to be taken from a book then which `Book` do you expect to be selected?

Comment: I expect that value of Book's phID will be changed to phId#3

Answer (score 1):

Your `Book` class should have a `Property` containing a list of `phId's` of all avaliable `PublishingHouses` like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<int> PhIdList {get; set;}
```

then your `DataGridComboBoxColumn` changes like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="PhIDs" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding phID}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding PhIdList}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding PhIdList}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

**EDIT**

> If i do so, every object of Book will contain identical collections of avaliable PublishingHouses. That's very unefficient by memory. Is it any other solution?

To prevent data redundancy you can define `PhIdList` in the *parent class* (e.g. a book-list container view-model if you're using mvvm) and get `ComboBox` data like this:

```
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding phID}" DisplayMemberPath="" >
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.BooksContainerVM.PhIdList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.BooksContainerVM.PhIdList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: If i do so, every object of `Book` will contain identical collections of avaliable `PublishingHouses`. That's very unefficient by memory. Is it any other solution?